# How to display custom posts type in select field of a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a job portal website in which I am using the WP Job Manager plugin by Automattic. When I add a new job using this plugin, it show a field in meta box having label "Company Name"

[image: click to see the image]

Somehow, I managed to find the metabox file of this plugin and the code of company name field is given below in the image:

[image: click to see the image]

I've changed the type of this field from text to select and added some options like below:

[image: select code image]

[image: field name image]

Now instead of custom options, How to show posts from a custom post type in this dropdown?

Comment: If you want people to help you, try to make easy to access the info to give you an answer. Start pasting code and avoiding code images. Regarding the question, I do not understand exactly, you want to add a metabox select that allows you to choose a post between all the posts in a custom `post_type`?

Answer (score 0):

With WP Job Manager you can use `<?php the_company_name(); ?>` to display the Company Name. But I'm not sure if that still works after you changed the field type from a `text` field to a `select` field.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).